# ajax not work for django method

Tags: django

```
<li class="email"> 
    <label>Email: </label><br/> 
    <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" /> 
    <span class="error"></span> 
</li> 



jquery

$('#id_email').keyup(function() {
    var email=$(this).val();
    $.get("/register/validate" , {'type': 'email' , 'content': email,}, function(data){
    if (!data.is_valid)  {
        $(this).next().show().html(data.message); 
    }
    else {
        $(this).next().hide();
        $("li").next("li.username").slideDown({duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
    }
    });
});


view.py

def validate(request):
    count = {'is_valid': 1, 'message': '', }
    if request.is_ajax():
        content = request.GET['content']
        if request.GET['type'] == 'email':
            try: 
                validate_email(content)
            except ValidationError:
                count['is_valid'] = 0
                count['message'] = 'Please input valid email'

    json = simplejson.dumps(count)

    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

it doesn't work when i keyup, why?

Comment: I know the reason, it is due to 'this' scope: '   $('#id_email').keyup(function() {
        var email=$(this).val();
        var proxy = this
        $.get("/register/validate/" , {'type': 'email', 'content': email,}, function(data){
            if (!data.is_valid) {
                $(proxy).next().show().html(data.message); 
            }
            else {
                $(proxy).next().hide();
                $("li").next("li.username").slideDown({duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
            }
        });
    });'

Comment: It would help if you explained a little more than "doesn't work." What was the error you got? Do you know if the get request was sent? Is there a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are placing extra ); in your jquery keyup function, please remove second last ); in your code and try to run again your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra comma here after `email,`:

```
$.get("/register/validate" , {'type': 'email' , 'content': email,}, function(data){
```

Comment: i have found that it is due to the scope of $(this). The way is to use one variable to store it. Any way, thanks!